# Watchman installation fails on mac os version 10.12

Tags: javascript, react-native, homebrew, macos-high-sierra, watchman

I'm trying to set up the development environment for **react-native** on my MacBook Pro 2012.
I'm trying to install **watchman** with **Homebrew** as the documentation suggests but I get this error and the build fails:

```
Error: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull-requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.
```

I'm fairly new to **mac os** and I don't know how to fix this. I read a lot about it and there does not seem to be a fix for my situation.

Comment: The error is fairly self explanatory. You'll need to update your version of MacOS. Try updating MacOS to the latest you can for the hardware.

Comment: I think this version is as far as I can go, is there any other way that I can get it working if I can't update it?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry about your installation issue, but homebrew does only support the latest macOS three versions, which would be `Mojave` (10.14), `Catalina` (10.15), `BigSur` (11.0).

With the most recent release `Monterey` (12.0), the Mojave artifact would be dropped pretty soon. So you can to build from source yourself.

I would recommend you to upgrade to a more recent macOS version to have a smooth formula installation experience.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have already updated my mac to Catalina and it works fine, but I would need to install XCode soon in the future and as I have come to find out that it requires Max OS Big Sur or later, and my device is not supported for that upgrade, is there any workaround to this or I'll just have to patch my system to upgrade to a higher version of Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to install Facebook watchman in High Sierra 10.13.6 using MacPort tools.

1- Download MacPorts package related to your version from: https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing

2- Extract and install it.

3- Run `$sudo port -v selfupdate` for any update.

4- Once successfully installed run the command: `sudo port install watchman`

For more details check the following documentations:

- https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html
- https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing